# Completely antisymmetric tensor products

Tags: tensor-calculus

Say $\epsilon_{abcd}$ denotes the fully antisymmetric tensor (with Lorentz indices), i.e. $\epsilon_{abcd}=\varepsilon_{abcd}$ where $\varepsilon_{abcd}$ is the symbol with $\varepsilon_{0123}=1$. Let us adopt the -+++ convention for the eta metric. Then, $\epsilon_{abcd}\epsilon^{efgh}=-\delta^{efgh}_{abcd}$ where the rhs is the generalized Kronecker delta. Let us assume that we somehow are confronted with a product of 3 such tensors. Then, 
$$
\epsilon_{abcd}\epsilon^{efgh}\epsilon_{pqvw}=-\delta^{efgh}_{abcd}\epsilon_{pqvw}=-\delta^{efgh}_{pqvw}\epsilon_{abcd}.
$$
Of course there is also a 3rd "contraction" between the first and third tensor, but for my question this example is enough. This question may be naive, but right now I cannot see it. How can we analytically prove the equality between the second and the third term (without writing the gKd as epsilons of course). One can always brute force this with matrices, but I am not interested in this approach. Contracting is also not an option here, because this lies inside a scalar expression in my case.

I was suspecting that this can be proved by using the identity $
\epsilon_{[abcd}T_{e]fg\dots}=0
$ in some non-trivial way, where $T_{abc\dots}$ is a tensor of arbitrary rank. This holds in 4 dimensions. Of course, one can antisymmetrize in more than 5 indices, and still the result is vanishing. However, the calculations get really messy, and thus, I cannot use this to prove my case. Does anyone know of a nice compact way to show this?

**Update**
To make this more clear, the question can be reformulated in the following way. Contracting the previous equation with $T_{efgh}$, one finds that
$$
T_{[abcd]}\epsilon_{pqvw}=T_{[pqvw]}\epsilon_{abcd}
$$
where $T$ is in general asymmetric. This is a simple case, but in complex expressions, "contracting" the epsilons in different order (meaning different deltas) can produce different quite complex expressions such that it is very hard to prove the equality between them after expanding everything. So I have traced the problem back to the first case, and I am just asking if there is a possible way to prove the last equality without using the deltas for example, just some kind of antisymmetrization trick or something like that

**Example**
Say you have $$V^{abcd} V^{efgh} \epsilon_{abef} \epsilon_{cd}{}^{pq} \epsilon_{ghpq}$$
where $V$ is antisymmetric in {a,b} and {c,d}, no paircom symmetry. Using this thing I am talking about one finds that $$
-4 V^{abcd} V_{cd}{}^{ef} \epsilon_{abef} + 4 V^{abcd} V^{ef}{}_{cd} \epsilon_{abef} + 16 V^{ab}{}_{a}{}^{c} V_{c}{}^{def} \epsilon_{bdef} - 4 V^{ab}{}_{ab} V^{cdef} \epsilon_{cdef}=0
$$
So you get the point, that this is actually very hard to prove (at least for me).

Comment: The title talks about contractions, but I don't see any contractions here. A contraction in Einstein index notation would be a repeated index.

Comment: This is why I used contractions with "". There is no real index contraction, this is merely products of epsilons. It is known that two epsilons give a gKd times the signature of the metric. This is everywhere in the literature

Comment: Your equation is indeed correct, but I don’t see what your question is. You already proved what you wanted to show, essentially starting from the definition of the Kronecker delta. If you want it to be shown a different way, what assumptions are allowed?

Comment: The identity is $\varepsilon^{p_1 ... p_m q_1 ... q_n} \varepsilon_{s_1 ... s_m q_1 ... q_n} = - m! n! \delta^{p_1 ... p_m}_{s_1 ... s_m}$

Comment: let me pose the question in a different way. Isolate the second and third term in the equation. Can we prove this equality without writing the delta as epsilons?

Comment: yes what you are writting @bolbteppa is correct, but this is just to show the factors when having same indices. If no same indices are to be found, then the identity is as I wrote it.

Comment: I'm sure you can, but the proof would look an awful lot like just equating both terms to the first one...

Comment: Roughly the first identity goes something like 
$$\delta^{efgh}_{abcd} \varepsilon_{pqvw} = (\delta_{abcd}^{1234}  \delta^{efgh}_{1234} ) ( \delta_{pqvw}^{1234} ) = (  \delta^{efgh}_{1234}  \delta_{pqvw}^{1234} ) (\delta_{abcd}^{1234}) = \delta^{efgh}_{pqwv} \varepsilon_{abcd} $$
using properties from e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta) and [this](http://ftp.aip.org/epaps/j_math_phys/E-JMAPAQ-40-033903-35/E-JMAPAQ-40-033903-35.pdf).

Comment: @bolbteppa while this proof is correct, it is basically the same as writting the gKd in terms of two epsilon tensors, hence it is not what I wanted. Thank you however!